# Pythagorean theorem code, isNaN() function

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement

I am attempting to write a program that can solve the pythagorean theorem for 'a', 'b', or 'c'.

HTML:

```
<h2>Pythagorean Theorem</h2>
<form>
<input id = "aPythagoreanTheorem" type = "text" value = "a" size = "10"/> <sup>2</sup> 
+
<input id = "bPythagoreanTheorem" type = "text" value = "b" size = "10" /> <sup>2</sup>
 =
<input id = "cPythagoreanTheorem" type = "text" value = "c" size = "10" />  <sup>2</sup>
<br />
<input type = "submit" value= "Submit" onclick = "pythagoreanTheorem(); return false"  />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function pythagoreanTheorem(a, b, c) {
    a = document.getElementById("aPythagoreanTheorem").value;
    b = document.getElementById("bPythagoreanTheorem").value;
    c = document.getElementById("cPythagoreanTheorem").value;
    if ((a != 0) && !(isNan(a)) && (b != 0) && !(isNan(b))) {
        c = (a * a) + (b * b);
        document.getElementById("cPythagoreanTheorem").value = c;
    }
}
```

This `if` statement works :

```
if ((a != 0) && (b != 0)) {
    c = (a * a) + (b * b);
    document.getElementById("cPythagoreanTheorem").value = c;
}
```

But when I attempt to also test if the user inputted value is a letter using `isNan()`, it stops working. Am I doing this incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

That should be `isNaN()` instead of `isNan()`. Javascript is case-sensitive.

See the documentation [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/isNaN), and also note all the warnings about the use of `isNaN()` on the same page.